# How to reset input element style

Tags: html, css

I have a form where i have a:

```
<input type="file" size="6" />
```

Unfortunately the button will be shown in the input bar!
This because I had set up a css for all inputs in the form:

```
#msform input, #msform textarea {

    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 29px;


    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;

    font-size: 12px;
}
```

please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kg48vpfq/
How can i clear the css for this input element only or maybe better how can i get the input box next to the button.

Thanks

Comment: You want the button to show completely? It should not cut. right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `height: auto` to the `file input`. Add this after the common styles for `input` and `textarea`.

```
#fieldset2 input[type="file"] {
    height: auto;
    border: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kg48vpfq/8/)

```css
#msform fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  display: none;
}
#msform label {
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
/*inputs*/

#msform input,
#msform textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 80%;
  height: 29px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: montserrat;
  color: #2C3E50;
  font-size: 12px;
}
#msform textarea {
  min-height: 100px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
#fieldset2 input[type="file"] {
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<form id="msform">
  <fieldset id="fieldset2">
    <input type="file" size="6" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: the input box still stays behind the button, it needs to be next of it

Comment: @bboni The button itself is file `input`

Comment: I mean you see a grey border around the text and button that one needs to be only around the text no file chosen

Comment: @bboni You need Javascript for that

Comment: @bboni Updated answer

Comment: is it also possible to get border:1px just around the text:no file selected

Answer (score 1):

try use `:not` selector:

```
#msform input:not([type=file]){
  ....
}
```

it will exclude your css rules for `type="file"`

http://jsfiddle.net/kg48vpfq/3/

Answer (score 1):

Change your **input** selector to `input:not([type=file])`

`input:not([type=file])` select all input element but input with type attribute **='file'**

```
#msform input:not([type=file]), #msform textarea {

    padding: 15px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    width: 80%;
    height: 29px;


    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: montserrat;
    color: #2C3E50;

    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your anwser it works but if i put a <input type="button> in the fieldset then it won't take the css anymore: please have a look: http://jsfiddle.net/kg48vpfq/5/  if you remove :not([type=file]) then the button gets the correct css otherwise not

Comment: [SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Arif_Iqbal/kg48vpfq/6/) change your code `#msform fieldset:not(:first-child) { display: none; }` and please if this is helpful for you please check accepted anwer

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, then you can fix it with some styles on the input file element

```
#msform input[type="file"] {
    width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    height: auto;
}
```

**Fiddle** http://jsfiddle.net/pa9r9pzj/

Answer (score 0):

Try like this : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kg48vpfq/1/)**

Specify styles for only the elements you need instead of giving in general, In your code the style will be applied for all the input types like textbox, submit, password etc.. so its better to be specific, For file type, you can use `input[type=file]`

```
#msform input[type=text],#msform input[type=password], #msform textarea {
    ...
    ...
}
```

instead of

```
#msform input, #msform textarea {   .....   }
```

Answer (score 0):

There's several way to achieve what you want.

You can either change your css definition on your input in order it does not apply to the ainput file

Or you can add a class to you input file like this

```
 <input class="no_border" type="file" size="6" />
```

And disable border for input with this class

```
#msform input.no_border {
    border: none
}
```